# Countable additivity and Lesbesgue-Stieltjes measures

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}_0(\mathbb{R})$ be the field of finite disjoint union of right semi-closed intervals. Let $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  be a non-decreasing right continuous function.

Then the set function $\mu(a,b]=F(b)-F(a)$ on right semi-closed intervals is finitely additive on $\mathcal{F}_0(\mathbb{R})$. Lemma 1.4.3 in [Robert Ash](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=GkqQoRpCO2QC) proves the countable additivity of $\mu$.

In the proof, $F_n(x)$ is defined as follow,
$$
F_n(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            F(x) & \quad -n \leq x < n \\
            F(n) & \quad n \leq x \\
            F(-n) & \quad x < -n
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Now $F_n(x)$ is assumed to be finite for all $n$. But this is not true for all distributions functions. Consider for e.g.
$$
F(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{1}{-x+1} & x < 1 \\
            \infty & \quad 1 \geq x
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Please point out, where I am wrong.

Comment: In Definition 1.4.1 of that book a distribution function is defined to be a map $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, so your $F$ is not a disitribution function in this sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your first paragraph, you require $F:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Your $F$ in the example does not satisfy this condition.